# How do I count if a number appears once per group in an array

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm running a report where I need to count if integers have appeared in an array; however, I can only count them once per group.

Therefore if I'm looking for `3` in the following groups.

```
Tim  
 1,2  
 1,3,4  
 3  
 3,6,7  

Beth  
 1,3  
 2  
 7,8  

Luke  
 1  
 2,4  
 1
```

I would get a count of `2` because it's appeared in two groups despite the fact that it's appeared more than once in the one group.

Comment: What does your current "count"-formula look like?

Comment: Right now just doing a distinct count in a running total for each integer. But of course that will give me counts over 1 for certain groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear how you're looking for the number `3` inside the array.

Because of this, I assumed that there's a formula `{@ThreeAppearedInArray}` that returns `True` if `3` is found in the array else `False`.

Then you should get the desired result like following:

Create a formula, let's call it `{@ThreeAppeared}`

```
If {@ThreeAppearedInArray} Then
    {yourTable.PersonName}
Else
    "#notAppeared#"
```

Then create following formula to show the distinct count:

```
// distinct count of the formula {@ThreeAppeared}-1 (to subtract the "#notAppeared#" value)
DistinctCount ({@ThreeAppeared})-1
```

**EDIT**

According to your comment, the formula should look like following:

```
If Instr({staff_sales.upgrades12}, '1') > 0 Then
    {yourTable.PersonName}
Else
    "#notAppeared#"
```

It is important that the formula returns the column you used to group the persons.

Replace `{yourTable.PersonName}` with the appropriate column.

Then do a distinct-count on that formula minus 1.

Comment: I'm a little lost. What I have is  If Instr({staff_sales.upgrades12}, '1') > 0 then 1 else 0 Would I then do a distinct count on that minus 1?